# spark-submit gives error as The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: apache-spark

**Command for which error occurs**

```
D:\eclipse_scala\WordCount>spark-submit --class "main.scala.WordCounter" --master "local[*]" "D:\eclipse_scala\WordCount\target\scala-2.11\word-count_2.11-0.1.j
ar"
```

**Error**

> The system cannot find the path specified.

I have written simple wordcount program in `scala` and compiled using `sbt`.
Version of spark - `spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar`

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71

Path=E:\software\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Users\xxxxxxx\hadoop\bin;C:\Program F
iles\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
 Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\oracl
exe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:
\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Window
sPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\
WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;E
:\software\spark\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try without double quotes 
spark-submit --class main.scala.WordCounter --master
local[*] D:/eclipse_scala/WordCount/target/scala-2.11/word-count_2.11-0.1.jar

Comment: Thanks pradipmw. Now new issue seen                                          Warning: Skip remote jar D:/eclipse_scala/WordCount/target/scala-2.11/word-count
_2.11-0.1.jar.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.scala.WordCounter

Comment: Instead of giving complete path, jar is copied to current location an it solve the problem.